# Verify existence of two columns in different tables in a single SQL transaction

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, multiple-tables

I'm trying to verify if data exists in two different tables in a single transaction. The reason for the single transaction is the database gets hit about 1-3 million times a day so adding anymore than 1 extra transaction would increase that number up to 9 million, and my poor little server needs a break :)

So I need to check if an ID exists in table X and table Y and return the results to my VB.net script so I can handle the outcome Ideally something like this would work

```
if exists (select id from X where id = @id)
print 'True,' else print 'False,'
if exists (select id from Y where id = @id)
print 'True' else print 'False'
```

Which gives me "True, True" if exists in both or "True, False" etc etc... But that only displays in SQL print and not actually returning it as an object/string or array values that I can use.

I'm open to any sort of solution of this nature that can give me two results from a single transaction and how to handle that response in vb. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Case When EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM X WHERE id = @id) Then 1 Else 0 End AS IsInX,
    Case When EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Y WHERE id = @id) Then 1 Else 0 End AS IsInY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select COUNT(*) from X where id = @id) AS x_exists,
       (select COUNT(*) from Y where id = @id) AS y_exists
```

This returns one data row with two fields, each containing either `0` or `1` (or more, if `id` is not unique).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckIDOnTables(@ID int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @X AS NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Y AS NVARCHAR(10)
Set @X = 'False'
Set @Y = 'False'
if exists (select id from TableX where id = @ID) 
    Set @X = 'True'
if exists (select id from TableY where id = @ID) 
    Set @Y = 'True'
SELECT @X AS XExists, @Y AS YEsists
END
```

It will give you your desired results.